# VB Dot Net Print Preview Datagridview of multiple columns on separate pages

Tags: vb.net, printing, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with around 30 columns in it. I need to achieve Print Preview and Printing functionality for this. At present I am able to preview data on one page but only for limited number of columns and other columns are not printed. How can I achieve the Print Preview of multiple columns on seperate pages? I have referred this link : http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/181006-print-datagridview/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataGridView control in .NET 2.0 is an amazing data representation control, and contains many advanced features that we could benefit from. The only thing that is not supported by this control is the printing feature. Please follow this link as answer:- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13678/The-DataGridViewPrinter-Class

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this to add to your referred code:

```
                w = Math.Max(w, rc.width)
                If y + 2 > e.MarginBounds.right Then
                    e.HasMorePages = True
                    mRow -= 1
                    newpage = True
                    Exit Sub
                End If
```

Comment: Hi @Nidzaaaa ..I tried what you mentioned but not able to get what I require... Can you please tell me where to insert the above code you mentioned. May be I am doing it wrong. What should 'w' be declared in above code as? Please do the needfull. Thanks